# is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus

> is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}$ convergent for $x \in [-a,a] \forall a>0$ ?

Perhaps I could use the leibntiz test? but then how would I prove it its convergent?

Comment: The test you refer to work well.

Comment: Indeed, Leibnitz holds the key! Hint: You only need to show that the term $\sin\frac{x}{n}$ eventually starts decreasing and keeps converges to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I think the question is : where did you get stuck in using the Leibniz criteria?

Comment: You do know that it is allowed to ignore the first few summands when applying the Leibniz (or  any other) convergence test, don't you?

Comment: what do you mean by "the first few summands"?

Comment: Another approach is to use intermediate value theorem to bound $$\left|\sin\frac{x}{2k}-\sin\frac{x}{2k+1}\right| = \left|\cos(\xi_k x) \left(\frac{x}{2k}-\frac{x}{2k+1}\right)\right| \le \frac{|x|}{2k(2k+1)}$$ where $\xi_k \in (\frac{1}{2k+1},\frac{1}{2k})$.

Comment: You can use [Dirichlet's test](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441358/is-sum-n-1-infty-1n-sin-fracxn-convergent/441366#441366).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Taylor series we have
$$(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=_\infty\frac{x(-1)^n}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=u_n+v_n$$
and the series $\displaystyle\sum_n u_n$ is convergent by the Leibniz test and the series $\displaystyle\sum_n v_n$ is absolutely convergent so we can conclude.

Comment: Is there another approach than the Taylor series?

Comment: The Taylor series is the most direct and simple method but if you don't like it there's the method mentioned in achille hui's comment.